# Bucle para recorrer todos los errores del registro (PHP)

Tags: php, bucles

Tengo un formulario para registrar usuarios y tengo una variable llamada `$errors` donde concateno todos los errores que lanza el formulario.

Lo que quiero hacer hacer es es un bucle para recorrer he imprimir por pantalla en un listado todos los errores que lance el formulario.

```
if(empty($name)){
        $errors = 'Debes colocar tu nombre';
    }

    if(empty($surname)){
        $errors .= 'Debes colocar tu apellido';
    }

    if(empty($email)){
        $errors .= 'La direcci&oacute;n de correo electr&oacute;nico no puede estar vacio';
    }
```

Esta es la manera en que concateno los errores dentro de la variable `$errors` colocándole un punto antes del signo de igual **"="**

Espero me puedan disculpar porque anta donde tengo entendido este es un foro para solucionar errores.

Comment: Sin separador entre los errores no vas a poder saber donde termina uno y empeiza el siguiente. Creo sería mas conveniente guardar los errores en un arreglo, en lugar de concatenarlos en una cadena.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con array

```
<?php
$errors=array();

// Si estan vacíos, se le añadirá al array
if (empty($name)) { array_push($errors, "Debes colocar un nombre"); }
  if (empty($surname)) { array_push($errors, "Debes colocar un apellido"); }
  if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Debes colocar un correo"); }
?> 

// Si no hay errores lo imprimirá
<?php   if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>

//Imprimir los errores
<?php foreach ($errors as $error) { ?>
                    <p><?php echo $error; ?></p>
                    <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que los valores vienen en la super globlar `$_POST`  (o `$_GET`), dependiendo del método del formulario, podrías usar operadores ternarios para evaluar el estado de las variables y/o ir llenando el array de errores.

```
#Declaramos el array para ir guardando eventuales errores
$errors=array();
/*
    Verificamos cada clave del POST (o GET)
    Si está vacío, hacemos una entrada en el array de errores
    De lo contrario, se creará una variable con el contenido
    Cabe decir que luego puedes usar esa variable directamente
*/
$errors=array();
empty($_POST['name'])    ? $errors['name']="Escribe tu nombre"      : $name=$_POST['name'];
empty($_POST['surname']) ? $errors['surname']="Escribe tu apellido" : $surname=$_POST['surname'];
empty($_POST['email'])   ? $errors['email']="Escribe tu email"      : $email=$_POST['email'];
```

La lectura del array sería así:

```
#1º verificamos que el array no esté vacio
if($errors){
    #Lo recorremos e imprimimos sus claves y mensajes
    foreach($errors as $k=>$v){
        echo "Error con respecto a $k: $v\n";
    }
} else {
    /*
        No hay errores.
        Aquí puedes usar sin problema las variables:
        $name, $surname y $email asignadas en los ternarios
    */
}
```

**Ejemplo de salida en caso de error en todo:**

```
Error con respecto a name: Escribe tu nombre
Error con respecto a surname: Escribe tu apellido
Error con respecto a email: Escribe tu email
```

**PD:** Si no te interesa diferenciar los errores por clave en el array, puedes llenarlo simplemente así:

```
$errors[]="Texto del mensaje de error"
```

y la lectura se haría así:

```
foreach ($errors as $v){ 
    echo "$v\n"; 
}
```